API Call succeeds on localhost but fails in production
I have a Laravel 10 app running on php 8.2. Now i am facing difficulties with an api call in production. Just to clarify: the api works fine, it is one specific route causing problems.
This is the code from the API Controller:
public function indexContact(): JsonResponse
{
    return response()->json([
        'captcha' => Captcha::create('math', true),
        'categories' => ContactController::CATEGORIES,
    ]);
}

Captcha is imported with use Mews\Captcha\Facades\Captcha; from the mews/captcha package.
Now i get a Sentry issue saying Undefined property: Intervention\Image\EncodedImage::$encoded, which is thrown in the call stack of Captcha::create. The breadcrumbs say, that before the App thew the Error, the captcha got written into cache.
I tried making the API Call to the server myself and received an 500 Internal Server Error.
But when i boot up my local environment, which is on the same git version and run the API request there, it succeeds witout Issue. I have checked and compared package versions and code and both localhost ond production have the same composer lock entry. There are no Errors when deploying. I am thankful for any help.

There’s obviously some difference between your local and production environments. Read the stack trace for the error in your production environment, and it will hint to what the actual problem is. My guess would be maybe the GD extension is not installed/enabled in production or something.

the gd extension is installed and enabled. Stack trace only traces through laravel kernel stuff.

It was only a guess. Like I say, you need to read the stack trace for the actual error.

If local and remote environment are absolutely identical I suggest you to clear laravel caches (specifically route caches) by running
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear

Also double-check php extensions, enabled php version, and installed packages
composer show -i
php -i

And try to update/rollback Intervention\Image, this issue is encountered by other people too, guess due to Intervention\Image recent updates
